# osmnx-retrieved dataset to be configured as basis for ArcGIS Pro gtfs network analysis

Tags: python, openstreetmap, arcgis, osmnx, network-analysis

I would like to configure a network dataset that I created using osmnx and arcpy to be compatible with gtfs data and do multimodal network analyses in ArcGIS Pro afterwards (possibly automated).

The download and setup of the dataset work fine, however I found that the classification of roads (OSM: highway; ArcGIS: ROAD_CLASS) are not easyly brought together, or rather transformed from the former to the latter. For example: roundabounts seem to be marked in Points in OSM data, but ArcGIS expects it to be in the ROAD_CLASS field of Lines.

Is there some proven or at least advisable way to configure OSM-Networks for the use in ArcGIS?

In general the osmnx-network works nicely as basis for the ArcGIS network analyst, but I can find very little information about this advanced stuff.

This is the tutorial from esri that I am following:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/create-and-use-a-network-dataset-with-public-transit-data.htm

And here are the attributes in question from ArcGIS
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/setting-directions.htm
... and OSM
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway

Thanks a lot if you have some suggestions or solutions for me!